# How can I make Nokia application compatibility?

Tags: c++, qt, compatibility

I developed an application in Qt with Symbian SDK C++, I could install the sis file to some phones for example Nokia 500. The SDK that I use is S60 SDK, I think.

Anyway, I tried to install this application to Nokia 2700 Classic but it gave me error like 'file format is not supported'.

How can I solve this problem, how can I install my application to lots of Nokia phones?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't.

Nokia 7200 does not use S60 and Symbian, so you can't run Symbian applications on it and it doesn't support SIS installation files.

The most portable applications among Nokia phones and phones with custom operating systems are those written in micro-edition Java aka J2ME.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and interest. But i have a problem, i want to develop and application that will receive incomming messages but how can I do it? i used this Qt and Symbian SDK and it works on S60 devices. Before, i used J2ME but it could't receive messages without using port. Is there anyway to receive messages without using port in J2ME?

Comment: You should ask this as a separate question.

Comment: satuon is right. Anyway I'm not a J2ME expert but there are many apps which can successfully receive sms, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful to the OS you are developping for :

- Nokia 500 : the OS is Symbian^3, which is a major version of Symbian just like S60v3 and S60v5 (aka Symbian^1). And S^3, S60v5 and S60v3 are not totally the same too.
- Nokia 2700 : its OS is S40. S40 is not S60/Symbian and it uses different ways for developing apps. There is no Qt port on S40 too.

You can have more informations about the Nokia phones and their OSes here : http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/

What you are doing is like trying to install a Windows program on Linux. It's a nonsense.